# Pinterest iOS SDK w/ Swift always returns "Cant convert value of type '(PDKResponseObject) -> ()' to expected argument type 'PDKResponseObject!'"

Tags: swift, sdk, typeerror, pinterest

I'm trying to build a Pinterest iOS clone as an exercise -- first day using xcode and swift. I can't get any function that uses the Pinterest SDK to work properly. Every function gives a Type Error.

For example, here's the code I'm using for login:

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: UIButton) {
    PDKClient.sharedInstance().authenticate(
        withPermissions: [PDKClientReadPublicPermissions],
        from: self,
        withSuccess: { (success: PDKClientSuccess!) in
            print(success)
        },
        andFailure: { (failure: PDKClientFailure!) in

            print(failure)
        }
    )
}
```

I get back the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(PDKClientSuccess!) -> ()' to expected argument type 'PDKClientSuccess!'
```

If I do withSuccess: PDKClientSuccess! then I get the following error:

```
ViewController.swift:28:26: Cannot convert value of type 'PDKClientSuccess!.Type' (aka'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<(Optional<PDKResponseObject>) -> ()>.Type') to expected argument type 'PDKClientSuccess!'
```

If I just do withSuccess: { (PDKClientSuccess) in print("success") } xcode doesn't complain, but it also doesn't work properly.

The documentation seems to be a bit outdated, but here's how they expect the function to look:

```
- (void)authenticateWithPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
             fromViewController:(UIViewController *)presentingViewController
                    withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock
                     andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock;
```

Though based on the error messages I'm getting from xcode, the function is now called 'authenticate', 'withPermissions' is a parameter, and 'fromViewController' is now just 'from'.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was I was passing a function when it's expecting a closure. So the TypeError makes sense.

The correct code is:

```
PDKClient.sharedInstance().authenticate(
    withPermissions: [PDKClientReadPublicPermissions],
    from: self,
    withSuccess: { (success) in print(success ?? "succeeds") },
    andFailure: { (failure) in print(failure ?? "fails") }
)
```

Unfortunately this hasn't solved everything... I never hit the withSuccess or withFailure, but at least xcode doesn't complain.